# SQL Server 2000, Do queries executed sequentially?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2000, sequential, query-analyzer

I am not sure if my question is related with the tool for executing the queries. (I am using Query Analyser, Access and AQT generally).

For example I have two queries.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1

SELECT * FROM Table2
```

So, do the queries executed sequentially or at the same time? If the are executed at the same time, how to make them execute sequentially?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be tool-dependent, although every interactive tool I've used does it the same way (sequentially) and anything else would be extremely unusual behavior (and hopefully highlighted by the tool's docs). In Query Analyzer, they'll be sequential.

Comment: +1, theoretically a tool "could" run them at the same time, but i've never seen/used one.

Answer (score 0):

Query analyser runs each statement in a batch sequentially.

Given that they are both SELECT's it wouldn't actually matter whether they ran sequentially.